# Deluge with samba disk

Tags: raspbian, samba, deluge

I've just set up a deluge daemon with a web UI and all works fine.

I have an ASUS RT-N66U router (with [asuswrt-merlin firmware](https://github.com/RMerl/asuswrt-merlin) version  378.56_2)  connected to a USB disk (1TB) formatted with NTFS.
Using SAMBA, I shared this with the Raspberry Pi and set deluge to write to it.

At the beginning everything is ok, but then every 3 to 4 hours one or more torrents error.

Is this kind of problem related to the NTFS disk, network or Raspberry Pi? Any suggestions?

Comment: What about saving the torrent locally and then rsyncing to the NFS share?

Comment: I saved torrent directly on NFS share

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: Apparently there isn't an error, but deluge marks some torrent as error (RED), so I force recheck and download stars again, but sometime this not start at latest point.
Some completed download sometimes aren't recognized and they are downloaded again and again: for example if size of a complete torrent is 1.5GB this become 1.7

Comment: Hm, it kind of sounds like the connection gets interrupted. Do the SAMBA logs contain anything of interest?

Comment: Nope! I mount external drive in fstab :(

Comment: Right, but something is hosting the drive. That something must have logs.

Comment: In /var/log of my raspberry there isn't any samba folder or log. I need to enable it!

Comment: firmware of my router?

Comment: Exactly! I'm using an ASUS RT-N66U with wrt-merlin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33183/discussion-between-claudio-pomo-and-diederik-de-haas).